# Updating Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, compiling

I am trying to update my linux kernel.
I downloaded the latest one: 5.2.1 https://www.kernel.org/

When I run the command:

```
make localmodconfig
```

I get the following error:

```
using config: '.config'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1655 kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Error: could not get list of modules: No such file or directory
```

This is the guide i used (its german): https://basic-tutorials.de/debian-kernel-fuer-gameserver-optimieren/2/

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you get your /proc unmounted? Also, why not simply use `apt update`? Do you really need to compile the kernel by yourself?

Comment: Perhaps the OP wants to install the latest kernel, which - depending on the distro - may not be available in a package yet.

Comment: @Chinese Name No, why should I get /proc unmounted? And of course I did a apt get update

Comment: @dr01 what is an OP?

Comment: OP = Original Poster, you in this case ;)